# how to change multiple 3-dimensional arrays to a single 4-dimnsional array in python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to **store multiple images** in ***a single 4-dimensional array*** using python. how can I change it?

I have tried np.vstack, np.concatenate, np.hstack  like the following way
**image_all = np.concatenate([img_3, img_4], axis=0)**, but I am getting "***all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly***".

I tried to create new dimensions for the images but not working. I created like img_1 = (1, 428, 640, 3) and I did like that for all and tried to create new ndarray but not successful

Assume I have images with the following dimensions

```
img_1 = (428, 640, 3)
img_2 = (426, 640, 3)
img_3 = (426, 640, 3)
img_4 = (640, 480, 3)
img_5 = (640, 427, 3)
```

I expect my new dimensional array to be concatenate and has a dimension of ***(5, ?, ? 3)*** like the following
***img_all.shape = (5, ?, ?, 3)***

Comment: The error message in this case is quite clear: Since your images differ in their shape (img 1, 2&3 and 4&5 have differing shape[0], and 1&2&3, 4 and 5 differ in shape[1]), you cannot just easily merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays of different shapes cannot be combined in a single array the way you've asked. But you can easily resize the images to the same shape and then combine. You can use pillow library like so:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# List of images to be combined in a single array
images = [img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4, img_5] 

# Common shape
SIZE = (640, 480) # Any size you find suitable

# Convert into pillow images and resize
images_pil = [Image.fromarray(img).resize(SIZE) for img in images]

# Convert back and combine into single array
images_np_arr = np.array([np.array(img) for img in images_pil])


print(images_np_arr.shape) # prints (5, 640, 480, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Shariq, can I do without resizing them? when I resize, I loose some data. and If possible, my idea is to change them to dictionary list

Comment: @TewodrosLegesseMunea Dictionary list? Could you elaborate?